# Return inherted class from base class

Tags: java, generics

Is there possible to return inherited class from base class in java?
I've tried something like this but of course it didn't work:

```
public class Entity <E> {
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
         return id;
    }

    public <E extends Entity<E>> E setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
        return (E) this;
    }
}

public class Category extends Entity<Category> {
    private String name;
}

Category category = new Category();
category.setId(666); // this need to be type Category without casting.
```

Comment: Make your `E` parameter bounded at the class declaration. Don't make `setId` generic.

Comment: Why would you need such odd and ugly design?

Comment: To not repeat id setter/getter to every Entity. Why this is bad design?

Comment: Why does setId need to return anything?

Comment: To be able to write `new Category().setId(11).setName("Name")`

Comment: If you're trying to write a chainable Monad that works with subclasses - you can't do it (well, not without hideous hacking). I've tried!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that isn't possibly using generics, because all the type information are erased during compilation time, and then, at runtime, every `type` information is discarded. Is like saying that, at execution time, every type parameter are interpreted like an type Object, and the cast are automatically inserted knowing that no ClassCastException will be thrown. If the compiler can not guaranteed this, you probably will have warnings like the `unchecked warning`.

But i have one idea, i will just copy the code and see for yourself, thanks not to me, instead thanks to `covariant return types` :D

```
public class Main3
{
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Category category = new Category();
        category.setId (666L).getName(); // this need to be type Category without casting.
    }
    public static class Entity<E>
    {

        private Long id;

        public Long getId()
        {
            return id;
        }

        public <E extends Entity<E>> E setId(Long id)
        {
            this.id = id;
            return (E)this;
        }
    }

    public static class Category extends Entity<Category>
    {

        private String name;

        public String getName() // don't forget the good rule to use accesors :D
        {
            return name;
        }

        @Override
        public Category setId(Long id)
        {
            super.setId(id);
            return this;
        }
    }

}
```

Hope it helps a little!

Answer (score 0):

I've made something like this:

```
public class Entity <E> {
    protected Long id;

    public Long getId() {
    return id;
    }

    public E setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
    return (E) this;
    }
}
```

But friend of mine told me this is bad design and better approach is to make interface and implement it in every class:

```
interface Identified<E> {
    Long getId();
    E setId(Long id);
}
```

Why this would be better?